# Using Selenium to make Instagram Bot

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a bot in Python that directly messages a user of my choice. I was able to code everything up and until selecting 'Message' on the persons profile.

Part of the code that works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint


chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/JACOB/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe' 
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(3)

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('MYUSERNAME')
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('MYPASSWORD')

button_login = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div > div > form > div > button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF')
button_login.click()

sleep(4)

notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button.sqdOP.yWX7d.y3zKF')
notnow.click()

sleep (4)

postnotifications = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
postnotifications.click()

sleep(3)

mydms = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a/svg')
mydms.click()

search = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')
search.send_keys('INSTAGRAM_USERNAME')

sleep(2)

foundit = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div/div[2]/div/span')
foundit.click()

sleep(3)
```

This code takes me all the way to a users page. However when I attempt to 'click' on the Message button, the xpath can't be found. Here is the code:

```
message = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/button')
message.click()
```

I found the xpath by right clicking on the Message button > Inspect > Highlighting the HTML code on the right hand side > Copy > Copy XPath.

I've also tried the full xpath and it can't seem to find it either.

Here is a screenshot of the button I'm referring too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code, and tried to make what you want. I manage to make selenium go to the messages of the user you want to send the message to.
Here is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/JACOB/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe'
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.maximize_window()
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('username')
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('password')

button_login = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div > div > form > div > button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF')
button_login.click()

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button.sqdOP.yWX7d.y3zKF')))

notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button.sqdOP.yWX7d.y3zKF')
notnow.click()

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')))

postnotifications = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
postnotifications.click()

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/a')))


WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')))

search = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')
sleep(2)
search.send_keys('Username')

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div/div[2]/div/span')))

foundit = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div/div[2]/div/span')
foundit.click()

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/button')))

webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/button').click()
```

I replace all the sleep() functions with the line to wait that the element is loaded. I think that your problem was that your script tried to locate the element before it was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking the « message » button, you should put this line :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ‘//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/button’)))
```

And import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

It will wait until the button is loaded and then click it.

If it is still not working, you can just try other methods to click the button, like css_selector, class_name Id...

Comment: thank you for this! however I still wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't working.

I used this link as well: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html to make sure i'm using the correct tags and such..no luck!

and downloaded an extension to confirm I was using the right XPath (and I am).